# Complementary Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

In $\mathbb{R}^4$ we have a subspace of all 4-tuples $(a,b,b,c)$ where the second and third component are equal. Is there a complementary subspace that completes it to $\mathbb{R}^4$? 
(we need another subspace that is a direct sum of this one)

Comment: "another subspace that is a direct sum of this one" is incorrect.

Comment: You are absolutely right...You know what I meant.....

Comment: No, I do not know exactly what you mean.  I think it would improve the question if you share what that is.

Answer (score 2):

I am not $100$% sure that I understand what you are asking, but using the idea of a complementary subspace from [PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/complementarysubspace): The space that you have, call it $W$, has as a basis $\{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,1,0), (0,0,0,1)\}$. It is three dimensional. Let $W'$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ with basis $(0,0,1,0)$. Then you have

$$
\mathbb{R}^4 = W\oplus W'\quad \text{a direct sum}
$$

Comment: I think to be a "complementary subspace" it also has to be orthogonal to the given subspace, but I could be misinterpreting it.

Comment: @EricStucky: That is probably true. I will wait to see if the OP responds. Thanks.

Comment: In a general vector space $V$, a complement to a subspace $W$ is a subspace $U$ with $V = U +W$ and $U \cap W = \{0\}.$ Given the additional structure of an inner product space, we can speak of orthogonal complements with the additional property that $U \perp W.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Thanks for the comment. I was guessing that that was what the OP was getting at.

Comment: It's not really clear what he intended, but your answer is right for the question as asked. If he did want an orthogonal complement, the space spanned by $(0,1,-1,0)$ would do (and is in fact unique, given the orthogonality requirement).